# Building a predictive model on time-series data whose quality decreases with age

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, cross-validation, predictive-models, hyperparameter

Suppose you have a time series dataset over the period of 10 years, and are trying to build an elastic net model. You know that for this particular dataset, the **noisiness of its records gets worse with age**; you observe that after 5 years, using the older data actually *harms* the prediction accuracy more than it helps.

Suppose that the noise gets so bad for certain features at some age that substituting the mean of future values is preferable to using recorded values, and some other features do not suffer from the noise problem.

How would you optimize for the amount of training data to use with 20 features and an unknown amount of noise affecting each feature differently with age? My intuition is that this choice (amount of training data history to use for each feature, up to the point where the mean potentially gets substituted) should be done inside the inner cross-validation loop, but I'm not sure if that's really necessary.

Comment: It seems like you're operating from some unstated premises (such as that it makes sense to replace old data with information based on more recent values rather than say - at least in some situations -  downweighting by age). It may well also make a difference what kinds of models you're contemplating. I believe it would help to try to make your situation and assumptions about what is appropriate more explicit.

Comment: Let's suppose it might actually be best to apply downweighting by age for *some* features (which adds yet another dimension to decision criteria) and we're using elastic net.